# jQuery scroll function: offset by height of fixed header

Tags: jquery, scroll, navbar

I'm using the following jQuery click function to jump to various sections of a long scrolling page (by anchor ID) that also factors in-- and thus offsets by-- the height of a fixed navigation header:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).attr('href');
    var elWrapped = $(el);

    scrollToDiv(elWrapped,75);
    return false;

});
function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){
    var offset = element.offset();
    var offsetTop = offset.top;
    var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;

    $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 500);
}
```

This works very well, however, the only downside with this approach is I have to define an amount by which to offset the scroll from the page top-- in this case, by 75px, i.e the height of the fixed header. For cases in which the height of the fixed header may change-- say for mobile via media query-- this height will likely be inaccurate, and the links won't offset by the correct amount of space.

Thus, I'm wondering how I might change/augment this function by calculating the actual height of the header and offset by that amount, **plus** say 10 additional pixels to account for section padding.

Thanks for any assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height of the header when a button is clicked.

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
    var el = $(this).attr('href');
    var elWrapped = $(el);
    var header_height = $('#header-id-goes-here').height() + 10;
    //var header_height = $('#header-id-goes-here').outerHeight(); You might need outerHeight if you have padding and borders

    scrollToDiv(elWrapped,header_height);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: One other related question-- if I wanted to add a static value of additional pixels to `height()` or `outerHeight()` is that possible to specify for `var header_height`?

Comment: Ah that's simple enough! Thanks David.